# Regex based SQL queries sqlalchemy-hana

Tags: sqlalchemy

Are regex based SQL queries supported by sqlalchemy-hana?
what should be the appropriate syntax for executing this SQL query and getting back the resulting pandas dataframe
`SELECT ATTRIBUTE_VALUE FROM PARSING2 WHERE (ATTRIBUTE_NAME NOT REGEXP "^ADDITIONAL")`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax - WHERE (ATTRIBUTE_NAME NOT REGEXP "^ADDITIONAL") is not supported by SAP HANA.

SAP HANA uses a SQL function named LIKE_REGEXPR for regular expression matching. For further details have a look at:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/b40d483dd34d47aa9cc89b4d8a6e617e.html